# Please can somebody suggest correct code for a repeated measured ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

A similar question is on Stack Overflow by a different user, however, there is no answer yet.

I am trying to compare the difference in gene expression between three groups (control, disease 1 and disease 2) over time ( measurements collected at two timepoints), and to also make a within group comparison, comparing time point 1 with time point 2.

I understand I can use the anova_test function to specify both between and within subject comparisons.

```
anova_test(data, formula, dv, wid, between, within, covariate,
 type = NULL, effect.size = "ges", error = NULL,
   white.adjust = FALSE, observed = NULL, detailed = FALSE)
```

https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/anova_test.html

The columns of my data frame with relevance would be the ones with genes (regarding just Gene1 here), the participant ID, DiseaseGroup ( 0 for control, 1 for disease 1, 2 for disease 2), Time (0 for timepoint 1, 2 for timepoint 2), Age, Gender ( the latter two I need as covariates). If I want to make the comparisons stated above my confusion lies with

a) the wid in the above specifies this as the column name containing individuals/subjects identifier, so participant ID in this case, and this should be unique per individual. However, the same ID number will appear twice, one for time point 1 and one for timepoint 2. Unless I code my second-time point ID with .sec. So if an individual's ID is 113 at time point 1, it will be 113.sec at time point 2?

b) secondly would my between and within comparisons ineffectively be stated the same? So 
       between=c(DiseaseGroup, Time) and within=c(DiseaseGroup, Time).

c) Lastly, as in the other post you can code for it in a different way. As stated in the website link above. He used this formula

```
output <- aov(Recall~(Task*Valence*Gender*Dosage)+Error(Subject/(Task*Valence))+(Gender*Dosage),ex5)
```

Where he put the within-subjects factors first within-subjects error term, followed by the between-subjects factors. I am uncertain how I would devise a formula like this taking into consideration the comparisons I need to make and not neglecting my covariates ( which if I include this from what I have read will turn this into repeated measures ANCOVA?). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `anova_test` function defined?

Comment: it is from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstatix/index.html